# Kubernetes Dashboard unknown field "seccompProfile" and error 503

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am a beginner with Kubernetes. I have enabled it from Docker Destop and now I want to install Kubernetes Dashboard.

I followed this link:

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started

And I executed my first command in Powershell as an administrator:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.4.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

I get the following error:

> error: error validating
> "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.4.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml":
> error validating data:
> ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.securityContext):
> unknown field "seccompProfile" in
> io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSecurityContext; if you choose to ignore these
> errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

In which case I tried to use the same command with --validate=false.

Then it went and gave no errors and when I execute :

```
kubectl proxy
```

I got an access token using:

```
kubectl describe secret -n kube-system
```

and I try to access the link as provided in the guide :

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

I get the following swagger response:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The error indicated that your cluster version is not compatible to use `seccompProfile.type: RuntimeDefault`. In this case you don't apply the dashboard spec (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.4.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml) right away, you download and comment the following line in the spec:

```
...
spec:
  # securityContext:
  #   seccompProfile:
  #     type: RuntimeDefault
...
```

Then you apply the updated spec `kubectl apply -f recommended.yaml`.